# java - Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook Unable to create sheets

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

In a much bigger code flow in my project I am trying to create a blank SXSSFWorkbook and create sheets and write data to it but I am unable to as its giving me a Runtime Exception of : No such file or directory. I do not understand why that is happening. I went through the code and could not find any reason.

Jars used:

```
poi-3.10-FINAL.jar
poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL.jar
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
>     at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:568)
>     at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:584)

Code :

```
csvDataWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(-1);
Sheet sheet = csvDataWorkbook.createSheet("csvDataSheet");
```

The second line above throws that exception. Might sound weird but this was working fine till yesterday, but has stopped from today.

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        .......
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What happens if you use Apache POI 3.12 beta 1 instead?

Comment: For all the different jars?

Comment: 431 ERROR - java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:637) ~[poi-ooxml-3.12-beta1.jar:3.12-beta1]
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:654) ~[poi-ooxml-3.12-beta1.jar:3.12-beta1]

Comment: What is your temp directory (TEMP/TMP) pointing to, and does that exist?

Comment: Its on a Linux server, thus /tmp must be the temp, thus no issue with access rights.

Comment: Does [File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) work on your system?

Comment: @Gagravarr : Yes it does work in a stand-alone file, then based on your suggestion, i changed the java.io.tmpdir to another location which is my project's temporary files directory and it worked. Can you tell me why this happened? I need to know as this is part of a huge system and I cannot leave it without understanding it.

Comment: The way that SXSSF keeps memory use down is by flushing most of the workbook to temp files when those rows aren't in use. Therefore, a working temp directory is required!

Comment: @Gagravarr : That issue is back. It pops up out of nowhere. File.createTempFile always works, but this issue is coming up after about 2 days . Does it involve any stream or handler closing/disconnect. Should I be deleting the poi-sxssf-sheet*.xml being generated in the /tmp ?

Comment: Are you perhaps failing to call the methods to tidy up when you're done working on the spreadsheet? eg [SXSSFWorkbook.dispose](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#dispose%28%29)?

Answer (score 5):

I have faced with exact problem during running integration tests with diff contexts.

There is a bug in POI.

SXSSF creates a temporary file when its saved using the class org.apache.poi.util.TempFile. When a tempfile is first created, the directory name is saved within this class, in the static singleton DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy object. This directory is only created on the first save and is automatically deleted when the virtual machine exits and its never checked if this directory still exists.

```
public File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) throws IOException {
            // Identify and create our temp dir, if needed
            if (dir == null)
            {
                dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "poifiles");
                dir.mkdir();
                if (System.getProperty("poi.keep.tmp.files") == null)
                    dir.deleteOnExit();
            }
```

So, if you have two applications both loading and saving excels and you then close one this directory is automatically deleted. Now both applications used exactly the same temp directory. Therefore if you try to save your file in the second application which is still open, an IOException is instead raised as it tries to create the tmp file in the no-longer existing directory.

For more details check [Bug 57200](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57200) - SXSSF saving fails sometimes as TempFile creation fails

Possible solutions:

- Use temp folder "java.io.tmpdir" instead of its sub-folder "poifiles".
- Use a unique temp folder name for each process instead of "poifiles".
- Never delete sub-folder "poifiles".
- Delete folder "poifiles" only if the user explicitely sets a corresponding system property, e.g. "poi.delete.tmp.dirs" (setting this property must also delete the contained temporary files even if "poi.keep.tmp.files" is specified).

I have fixed it by "never delete sub-folder. Create folder and do not use dir.deleteOnExit();

```
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),"poifiles");
dir.mkdir();
TempFile.setTempFileCreationStrategy(new TempFile.DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy(dir));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it on Apache, check whether the temp folder exist.

Can be found in tomcat7w.exe inside tomcat bin folder.

Refer below image,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6VGc.jpg

-Djava.io.tmpdir=

If the option is not available, try creating it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several jvm on the same server, I advise you to use version 3.12 and indicate yourself where you want to write :

```
File generateTempDir = ...
//OR File generateTempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),"poifiles");
TempFile.setTempFileCreationStrategy(new TempFile.DefaultTempFileCreationStrategy(generateTempDir));
```

(or set per jvm the java.io.tmpdir property)